# Rascal module not linking to Java class

Tags: java, rascal

I'm attempting to create a Socket library in Rascal to operate a Java TCP socket class.
For this the following basic setup is used: (src)>(Network)>(Socket.java, Socket.rsc)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a66RS.png

When attempting to import the Network::Socket module into a Rascal Terminal the following error occurs: "*Cannot link method Network.Socket because: class not found*"

The Rascal module:

```
module Network::Socket

@javaClass{Network.Socket}
public java str tester();
```

The Java class:

```
package Network;

import io.usethesource.vallang.IString;
import io.usethesource.vallang.IValueFactory;

public class Socket {
    private final IValueFactory values;

    public Socket(IValueFactory values){
        this.values = values;
    }

    public IString tester() {
        return values.string("lol");
    }
}
```

Please enlighten me why the linking between the module and class is not working, I dont see the issue.
Closing and opening a new terminal like suggested in [Referencing a Java file in Rascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53210300/referencing-a-java-file-in-rascal?rq=1) did not fix the issue.

Comment: Could be that the project is not set up for compiling Java code? If the .class files do not end up in a target folder, then the Rascal interpreter can not load the class and that would lead to this error.

Comment: I do believe it is. The compiler is shown in the project properties. Its using JDK 1.8.0_271. Should I maybe set the target folder somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault laid in some metadeta of the eclipse project being faulty.

> **Creating a new project** with the exact same setup and files made it work.

Edit: Believed **cause** of error is renaming the project

Comment: Do you have some details to share? Might help the next person who falls into this pit